# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Professional Crashes on Schema Compare

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SQL Server project in a solution.  I've made some updates to the database directly in SQL Server Management Studio and I want to update the SQL Server project in Visual Studio to match the schema of the database.  In Visual Studio when I select "Compare Schema" and choose the database as the source and the project directory as the target, and then click "Compare", the results of the compare are shown on screen, but then Visual Studio crashes immediately thereafter.  I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Professional with Update 2 installed, and I have Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 2015.  The following details show up in the Event Viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ImportDefinition)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ImportCardinality)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare.UI.ComparisonControl.SetSourceAndTargetScripts(System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.Object,System.Object>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.Object,System.Object>)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare.UI.ComparisonControl.ClearText()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareEditorControl.PopulateMainGrid(Boolean)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareEditorControl+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<HandleModelCompareCompleted>b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.InvokableAction.InvokeMethod()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.InvokableBase.Invoke() Exception Info: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.InvokeOnUIThread(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.InvokableBase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke(System.Action)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareEditorControl.HandleModelCompareCompleted(System.Object, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.DataModel.OperationEventArgs)
at System.EventHandler`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Invoke(System.Object, System.__Canon)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.DataModel.SchemaCompareDataModel.RaiseEvent[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.EventHandler`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.DataModel.SchemaCompareDataModel.Compare()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.DataModel.SchemaCompareDataModel.<CompareAsync>b__184_0()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.DataModel.SchemaCompareDataModel+<>c__DisplayClass204_0.<RunAsync>b__0(System.Object)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Did you ran VS as administrator?

Comment: Yes I'm running VS as administrator.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome, do you have the services for the SQL Server running?

Comment: Yes, the services are running - I can query the database I'm connecting to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to clear the `Visual Studio` cache in:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

By removing everything in this directory, and restart the Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked for me too!  I had to re-install the Data Tools and this broke VS, but this restored the functionality - thank you.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me as well - been digging around for a solution to this for a while - thanks! Any information on why this often is the solution?

Comment: You're very welcome to all of you :) @TylerNielsen I have no clue what is the specific reason, sorry bro. If I know why, I am going to let you know for sure :D

Comment: Seriously man, once I clear it, immediately I am able to expand the setting for schema compare. Thanks!